# is_object not returning expected result php

Tags: php

I'm working on a script where I can check permissions and stuff, and I stumbled across something odd.

My permission script can check systems and functions and see if the user is allowed to use m.

I'll explain with some code:

```
if(permission::check('factbounce', 'magklik')){
echo ' Yep good ';
} else {    
echo 'Nope not good';
}
```

Here I have a system factbounce and a function magklik, now inside the permission class:

```
public static function check($systemCode, $functionCode = null ){
        $instance = self::get();

        if($instance->checkSystem($systemCode)){            
            if(is_null($functionCode))
                return true;

            if(!$instance->checkSystemFunction($functionCode))
                return false;

            return true;

        }   

        return false;
    }
```

This piece of code of will trigger `checkSystemFunction`, and will check on magklik:

```
private function checkSystemFunction ( $functionCode ){

    if(!self::$oSystemFunction)
        self::$oSystemFunction = org_system_function::getByCode($functionCode);

    if(!is_object(self::$oSystemFunction));
        echo 'No Object';

    echo '<pre>'.print_r(self::$oSystemFunction, true).'</pre>';

    if(!self::$oSystemPermission->checkFunctionPermission(self::$oMedewerker, self::$oSystemFunction))
        return false;

    return true;        

}
```

The output of the code is this:

```
No Object
org_system_function Object
(
    [primaryKey] => org_system_function_id
    [table] => org_system_function
    [arAssoc] => Array
        (
            [function_id] => 1
            [name] => May click around
            [code] => magklik
            [description] => do what you want
        )

)
Yep good
```

I don't understand why it says no object, clearly when I print it it's an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are terminating your `if` clause with the trailing `;`:

```
if (!is_object(self::$oSystemFunction));
    echo 'No Object';
```

So `echo 'No Object'` will always get executed.

Comment: damn... :( i feel so dumb

Comment: @DavidEricsson: its normal you need to take a break and drink a coffee :)

Comment: also as an side note it also possible to make this random feature (bug) with (do) while, for and foreach loops.

Comment: One more reason to always use curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

You're terminating your `if` statement with a semicolon. So, the echo statement is being processed normally and will get executed every time you run the script.

This should work:

```
if(!is_object(self::$oSystemFunction)) 
    echo 'No Object';
```

But it's always a good idea to separate your if else blocks with curly braces.

```
if(!is_object(self::$oSystemFunction)) {
    echo 'No Object';
}
```

This increases the readabaility and maintainability of your code.

---

An example to demonstrate this:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

if ($a == $b);
echo 'foo';
```

The above code outputs:

```
foo
```

See the demo [here](http://codepad.org/kFUlv5aQ).